Deploy qgis-server+nginx with systemd
I installed qgis-server and nginx. I followed the official documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-debian-based-systems) and if i start the server with:
spawn-fcgi -s /var/run/qgisserver.socket -U www-data -G www-data -n  /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi

and open the example link:
http://qgis.demo/qgisserver?
  MAP=/home/qgis/projects/world.qgs&
  LAYERS=countries&
  SERVICE=WMS&
  VERSION=1.3.0&
  REQUEST=GetMap&
  CRS=EPSG:4326&
  WIDTH=400&
  HEIGHT=200&
  BBOX=-90,-180,90,180

I obtain the map, as the guide says.
However, if I  try to deploy the server using systemd units (services and sockets), as the linked oslandia tutorial, instead of the map I get

serverException: Project file error. For OWS services: please provide a SERVICE and a MAP parameter pointing to a valid QGIS project file

Does anyone know why?
Info:
OS: Debian 12.5
QGIS Server: 3.36.2

I had this error message and could fix it changing the directory and file permissions of the QGIS project. I'm not sure whats the right one, but having a look at a project which actually works fine I see that both directories /home/qgis as /home/qgis/projects/ and file world.qgs do have permissions set to 755.

I have already tried to give permissions to the directory/files (777), but doesn't work. As I said it works well with a single service/sockets, but it doesn't work using multiple services/sockets (see oslandia tutorial). For now i was able to run qgis server (and lizmap) with apache, which does not require the use of the services

Sometimes error messages are a bit misleading and this even could mean that QGIS has problems, for example, for reading a non existing layer file. So having a look at the QGIS Server logs definitely should give you a hint what the problem is.
